# Mediator is not registered

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, robotlegs

I have some problem with views and mediators. I have view named Shop and his mediator.

I mapped it in my context:
Code:

```
mediatorMap.mapView(Shop, ShopMediator);
```

Then I create object of Shop and add to stage just as user open shop in the game. The problem is that the mediator is not called at all in the application.

Anyone know what is the reason?

Below pasted a piece of my code.

Context initialization:
Code:

```
override public function startup():void
{
....
mediatorMap.mapView(Shop, ShopMediator);
...
mediatorMap.mapView(GameFace, GameFaceMediator);
...
}
```

Object of shop is create in GameFace:

Code:

```
public function initShop(aX:Array):void
    {
        shop = new Shop();
        _aX = aX;

    }
```

And was added to scene when player open shop in game:

Code:

```
public function openShop(tab:uint = 100):void
{
    shop = new Shop();
    addChild(shop);
    shop.init(_aX);
    shop.x = 396;
    shop.y = 267;
}
```

Of course object of GameFace was added to display list.
Someone know whats wrong is in my code?

Comment: Do you create a Context?

Comment: Yes, of course!

private function createContext():void
{
 _contextView = new Sprite();
 addChild(_contextView);
 _context = new AquaGameContext(_contextView);
}

Comment: "the mediator is not called at all in the application" - what do you expect in this case?

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but did you make sure that the mediator is listening to the correct events, and that those events are firing? All the code that you have posted so far seems alright...

Answer (score 0):

If your application set-up is anything like mine, you may not actually be creating/activating the mediator. The `mediatorMap` just keeps a map of components to the mediators that they need.

Try adding the code below to the constructors of both `Shop` and `GameFace`:

```
new LazyMediatorActivator(this);
```

This should ensure that your mediator gets activated when the `Shop` and `GameFace` hit the stage. The activator is found in the package `robotlegs.utilities.lazy`.

If that doesn't work, you may need to call `mediatorMap.createMediator(shop)` manually when `shop` hits the stage, but the built-in lazy option is preferable.